# jsp - Struts2 - Format a string to number with commas

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a string in my jsp which is holding a number (eg "numberString = 12345"). I want to display the string in number format with commas (ie 12,345).

I tried the following formatting but it's not working as the value i have is a string and not a number.

```
<s:property value="%{getText('{0,number,$###,##0.00}', {numberString})}"/>
```

Can you please suggest a way for doing this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're looking to do it in the jsp page, perhaps JSTL format function parseNumber will help you.

Reference: [JSTL Core  Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_parsenumber_tag.htm).

Their page shows this example:

```
<c:set var="balance" value="1250003.350" />
<fmt:parseNumber var="i" type="number" value="${balance}" />
```